# I am working vbscript in HTA. Using SQLite for database need. And SQLite doesn't recognize equal to an integer

Tags: sqlite, equality

The target field is pk_2013_1qrt and its type is integer. But when i run the query below, results includes pk_2013_1qrt=1 values too. 
Where did i go wrong?
Regards

```
SELECT *,ims_2012_modifiye.id AS imsID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id AS ilacID, 
         ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_adi_duzgun AS iaDuzgun 
FROM ims_2012_modifiye 
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id=ilaclar.id 
WHERE ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOTNULL 
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.asil_listede_mi=1 
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOT IN
      (SELECT ilac_id FROM piyasa_kontrol 
       WHERE pk_yil IN (2012,2011,2010,1900,1901)) 
OR
  ims_2012_modifiye.oncelik_verilsin_mi=1 
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt=0 
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OR` has lesser priority than `AND`. What you want is unclear, but the latest `AND ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt=0` is applied only to the rows with `ims_2012_modifiye.oncelik_verilsin_mi=1`. Maybe this:

```
SELECT *,ims_2012_modifiye.id AS imsID, ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id AS ilacID, 
         ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_adi_duzgun AS iaDuzgun 
FROM ims_2012_modifiye 
LEFT JOIN ilaclar ON ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id=ilaclar.id 
WHERE (ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOTNULL 
         AND ims_2012_modifiye.asil_listede_mi=1 
         AND ims_2012_modifiye.ilac_id NOT IN
           (SELECT ilac_id FROM piyasa_kontrol 
            WHERE pk_yil IN (2012,2011,2010,1900,1901)) 
       OR
         ims_2012_modifiye.oncelik_verilsin_mi=1)
  AND ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt=0 
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: This query is inside a for-next loop of vbscript. Loop choose randomly 1 record per loop from a list. But this top sold list must extract from larger list. Top list count number must decreased one by one in every loop to sure randomness keeped between first handled top list. I don't know how to do right :( Thank you (P.S. sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Is this comment supposed to add something to the question? Anyway, it's clear that `ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt=1` is possible in your code and it's clear *why*.

Comment: i want to watch and to be sure, sign records by 1 (integer) taken by random loop previously. Other records still 0 (integer) that not yet chosen by loop. I hope i could explain :(

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. As @Anton said AND has prior accessibility to query results. Move AND ims_2012_modifiye.pk_2013_1qrt=0 part just after to WHERE solves my problem. Thank you Anton, Regards